# ASP.NET how to add custom headers without creating HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-3.0, iis-6, asp.net-3.5

Is there any way to add custom headers without creating HttpHandler? I've tried the following two APIs but the former is throwing error and the latter is working fine but when the page is either redirected or posted to another page. The header is lost. Thanks for your suggestion.

```
    Response.Headers.Add()
    Response.AppendHeader()
```

Environment: ASP.NET 3.5 & IIS 6

Comment: Why don't you add it to the IIS server itself if you need it in every page (well i'm assuming) - Check this [link](http://kbalertz.com/954002/custom-response-header-hosted.aspx)

Comment: @DidierG ... The header information is only available at runtime so I am not able to add it in IIS server.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers.aspx):

> "The Headers property is only supported with the IIS 7.0 integrated
>   pipeline mode and at least the .NET Framework 3.0. When you try to
>   access the Headers property and either of these two conditions is not
>   met, a `PlatformNotSupportedException` is thrown."

Since you are using IIS6 I'd expect you to get a `PlatformNotSupportedException` exception raised. Are you?

Try using [Response.AppendHeader()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.appendheader%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) method instead. For example:

```
Response.AppendHeader("CustomAspNetHeader", "Value1");
```

You can also use [Response.ClearHeaders()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.clearheaders%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to remove any headers first, if need be.

Comment: In fact, I am also using Response.AppendHeader() method but when the page is cross-posted or redirected to another page, the header is lost.

Comment: I'd recommend using http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to view the headers being sent to try and ascertain what is going on, then...